# is there some R packages for generating shifted chisquare distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, chi-squared

I want to generate random variables from shifted to the left chisquare f(X-a).I have tried rchisq(10,1)-a but it is false, it is equal to f(X)-a not f(X-a).Is there some solution to generate random number from f(X-a),f=is the chisquare distribution??

```
desired_length<-1000
empty_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = desired_length)
empty_list1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = desired_length)
empty_list2<-vector(mode="list",length=desired_length)
empty_list3<-vector(mode="list",length=desired_length)
empty_list4<-vector(mode="list",length=desired_length)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  
  set.seed(i)
  h<-rchisq(10,3)
  set.seed(i)
  g<-rchisq(10,3)
  set.seed(i)
  g1<-rchisq(10,3)-0.5
  set.seed(i)
  g2<-rchisq(10,3)-1
  set.seed(i)
  g3<-rchisq(10,3)-1.5
  set.seed(i)
  g4<-rchisq(10,3)-2
  a<-cbind(h,g)
  b<-cbind(h,g1)
  c<-cbind(h,g2)
  d<-cbind(h,g3)
  e<-cbind(h,g4)
  empty_list[[i]]<-a
  empty_list1[[i]]<-b
  empty_list2[[i]]<-c
  empty_list3[[i]]<-d
  empty_list4[[i]]<-e
}

pvalue<-numeric(1000)
pvalue1<-numeric(1000)
pvalue2<-numeric(1000)
pvalue3<-numeric(1000)
pvalue4<-numeric(1000)
x<-numeric(5)

for (i in 1:1000){
  pvalue[i]<-t.test(empty_list[[i]][,1],empty_list[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue1[i]<-t.test(empty_list1[[i]][,1],empty_list1[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue2[i]<-t.test(empty_list2[[i]][,1],empty_list2[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue3[i]<-t.test(empty_list3[[i]][,1],empty_list3[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue4[i]<-t.test(empty_list4[[i]][,1],empty_list4[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
}
x[1]<-sum(pvalue<0.05)/1000
x[2]<-sum(pvalue1<0.05)/1000
x[3]<-sum(pvalue2<0.05)/1000
x[4]<-sum(pvalue3<0.05)/1000
x[5]<-sum(pvalue4<0.05)/1000
location<-seq(0,2,by =0.5)
plot(location,x,ylab="Power for chi3^2 distribution",xlab="location difference",type = "l",col="blue")
```

Comment: This question is really about how to generate random variables from a particular distribution, it's not particularly programming related.

Comment: @user2554330 it can be

Comment: @user2554330 when there is no built in function or a specific package then we must program it

Comment: @user2554330 but before one must be sure that there is no such package or built in function because i am really confused

Comment: You will be less confused if you think of this as a probability question.  You can get help with that on Cross Validated, not here.

Comment: @ZB you do seem to be confused. When you say `f(X)` is the chi square distribution, what is `X`? When you do `rchisq(10, 1)` that gives you 10 random samples from the Chi Square distribution with 1 degree of freedom. What is it that you are trying to take `a` away from? If you do `hist(rchisq(1000, 1))` and `hist(rchisq(1000, 1) - 2)` you'll see that `rchisq(10, 1) - a` must be what you are looking for. You obviously don't mean to take it away from 10 (which just gives you fewer samples) and you can't take it away from 1 - that lowers the DOF and doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AllanCameron Nice .But although we can not say that those random variables are derived or sampled from f(x-a) what you have done is just translation of  the curve of f(X) to the left .

Comment: @AllanCameron see for example. rnorm( 10,0,1) and rnorm(10,3,1) .The second equal f(x-3)

Comment: @ZB yes, that's right. The curve is translated to the left. In the normal distribution `rnorm(10, mean = x, sd = 1)`, you can translate left or right in two ways:. `rnorm(10, mean = x - a, sd = 1)` gives _exactly the same distribution_ as `rnorm(10, mean = x, sd = 1) - a`. The Chi Square distribution doesn't have a mean parameter, so you can only shift it using the second method. If translation to the left or right is not what you mean, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AllanCameron Nice question so now i will give a link of an article where you see at the bottom of the page number 415 the power curve of the t.test in case of random variables generated with a chisquared distribution, (a ctwo sample location problem): 
 https://eldorado.tudortmund.de/bitstream/2003/27803/1/DP_1911_SFB823_Fried_Dehling.pdf

Comment: @AllanCameron Now above is my code .please run it and you will get a bizarre curve .I am sure it is right coded because it works for all the others

Comment: @AllanCameron replace the rchisq with rnorm and you will get the power curve of the top left plot

Comment: f(X - a) is a shift to the right (not left) when a > 0. To shift the samples to the right, what you want is `rchisq(...) + a` instead of `rchisq(...) - a`. Of course, when a < 0, then it's a shift to the left.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks .but the question is how to generate randon variables from a chisquared distribution

Comment: Understood, `rchisq(...) + a` is exactly that. I think if you plot histograms of `rchisq(...)` and `rchisq(...) + a` you'll see the latter is a right-shifted version of the former (when a > 0).